# how to pass the string value one class to another for using json?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, json

I have problem with passing the string value class to another. In main class I have two spinner and date picker, 1st spinner is location, 2nd one is stock point name. When the location is selected it will displayed related stock point on 2nd spinner and selected date, I will pass to 3 field in URL for using JSON. item,item1,date are fields.

```
url0 = "http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/?Location="+item+"&GROUP="+item1+"&asondate="+date;
```

I want to pass the string url0 to another class, I passed it when I call that class it was force close the logcat show on

```
06-28 12:09:45.998      612-612/com.android.exchange           E/StrictMode: null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31660 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Please show us some code that you have tried so we could help you better.

Comment: It looks like the problem may be that you need to call `unBindService()`

Answer (score 0):

If u r using only one type of url and item,item1,date are varying then Pass Only three of your values in Intent and get it from Bundle in another class.U can set this values in your URL.

Pass the values:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_item", item);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_item1", item1);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_date", date);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get the Values in SecondActivity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String item = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_item");
String item1 = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_item1");
String date = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_date");
```

Now Set your url0.